# Is it possible to make nested table or to find a model without nested table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-relationship

Here is the problem: if I have a table like this:
|pokemon|type|stats|moves|
in the column move I want to refer all move not just one, and I can't make a list because I want to make a table move like this:
|moves|accuracy|power|
So is it possible to make nested table or there is a better way to organize my ERM(MCD in french) to get a good representation of this type of schema ?
And I don't want to make a table by pokemon it would be too huge. I wan to make less table as possible.

PS: I work with SQL server

Comment: The typical solution in a relational database model is to make a `PokemonMoves` table that links between these two tables. You could include information specific to the move for that Pokemon there as well, for example, if it learns the move by level up and if so, at what level.

Comment: If fact, create a table PokemonMoves is a good way but i don't know how to link these table for example, if I follow your example, I can create a table like this pokemon|move| like this I can have all move learned by all pokemon but there will be duplicates because if for example pikachu learned thunderbolt Raichu can learned thunderbolt too. So there will be at least 2 lines to represent this situation. So I want to avoid that, is it possible or the best solution is to make duplicates ?

Comment: The best solution is to make "duplicates" as you call them.   They aren't really duplicates, because the combination of Pokemon & Move is what makes each row unique.   To answer your question, there is no such thing as a "nested table" in SQL Server or any other relational DB that I know of.

Comment: Yes I know in fact this is not really duplicate but there will be a very HUGE amount of element in the tables, but it's okay ! Thanks a lot ! If there is any other solution tell me

Comment: This could be done by having a column to indicate Raichu is an evolution of Pikachu (by ID), and query (at runtime) the Pikachu moves to get a complete set for Raichu, or else define a "move set" (in another table) with its own identifier so you could link a Pokemon to an entire move set instead of individual moves. However, I'm pretty sure (though not absolutely sure) that move sets aren't perfectly regular like this, and you can find evolutions where the move sets are in fact not "logical", which means this setup would not be redundant. You can hack in evolved forms at L1, for example.

Comment: Wooow I really don't think about that, even it's a complex way to see the problem it simplify the situation and with this i can have a table with less element !

Comment: However, unless you create what you called "duplicates" (one row in the moveset table for each individual move), you will not be able to create a foreign-key relationship between the moveset table and the move table.  JOINs to the Move table will be difficult without it.